# exporting a function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, automation

I am using nodejs and webdriver for automation tests. I am trying to export a function from one js file to another. e.g there is a function called abc under file abc.js and i want to use that function with other file called xyz.js.  I tried using export and require but it exports and runs entire test (abc.js) instead of just a function.

```
//abc.js 
console.log('print this'); 
client= function client() {
driver.get(baseUrl + '/#/login'); 
};
exports.client = client;
//xyz.js
var client1 = require('abc.js').client();
```

Comment: ...where is the code?

Comment: Please edit that into the question.  It is difficult to read the way you have it formatted.

Comment: @AaronDufour ok i formatted the code

Answer (score 1):

Requiring a module for the first time causes the module to be cached and it's code to be executed, that's why you're seeing your "print this" log. Next time you call your `client` function you shouldn't see it.

This is not relevant to the question, but still, in your xyz.js file, since your function isn't returning anything you can use:

```
require('abc.js').client();
```

Instead of:

```
var client1 = require('abc.js').client();
```

In your abc.js, there's no need for a named function, you can just use:

```
var client = function() {
   ...
};
```

Comment: I tried multiple times but i still see "print this" log even if its outside of exported function.  Any other ideas?

Comment: ...again, when you require a module for the first time, all the code outside your functions gets executed, in this case your log. This behaviour is expected.

Comment: I guess I am confused.  When you say require a module for first time what do you exactly mean? I am new to node.js.

Answer (score 1):

give it a try

```
function abc(){
console.log('print this');
this.client= function client() {
driver.get(baseUrl + '/#/login');
};
return this;
}
module.exports  = abc;
//xyz.js
var abc = require('abc.js')();
abc.client();
```

its a good practice when capsulating objects in nodejs